# Selecting segments from segmented layer using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, image-segmentation

Is there a way to select the segments from a segmented layer in ArcMap?

I've created a segmented layer by running Segment Mean Shift, but I can't seem to find a way to select or isolate the segments. I was hoping for a way to, e.g., create a shapefile from a collection of segments. I see that Training Samples Manager offers manual picking, but I'm not trying to create training samples for classification. Also, manual picking would be laborious in my case.

Is there a way to select/isolate segments by applying a mask?

Comment: What is your desired end product? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: @Aaron I've changed the question to using ArcMap. I'm trying to extract the coordinates of each segment polygon. Ultimately it'll be used for training a deep learning model (outside of ArcGIS).

Comment: Why not convert the segments to polygon using Raster to Polygon? Alternatively, consider shifting your workflow to Orfeo Toolbox where you can export segments as polygons: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_LSMSVectorization.html

Comment: @Aaron I've tried converting Raster to Polygon, but is there a way to extract individual polygons and put them on a separate layer?

Comment: Which criteria would you use to select the polygons?

Comment: @Aaron Ideally, I'd like to extract the polygons that overlap with another layer of polygons. I've managed to view the overlapping polygons by generating Related data rows, but I can't seem to find a way to extract these polygons.

Comment: Once you generate vector polygons of your segments, you could intersect those with your other vector polygon layer.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not quite sure because I'm trying to extract whole overlapping polygons. AFAIK intersection cuts off the regions that do not overlap. I'm trying to get the whole polygons that have overlapping regions. Similar to [this](https://i.imgur.com/k5z0rOQ.png), but I cannot find a way to extract the polygons.

Comment: In that case, I would use “Select by Location” using a “completely contains”, or other overlap rule that meets your needs.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: Glad it worked. I included these comments as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a two-step approach:

1. Convert your raster segments to vector segments using [Raster to
   Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm).
2. Use [Select by Location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-by-location.htm) with a “completely contains”, or other
   overlap rule that meets your needs.